# mysql bind_param variable types why not following the rules

Tags: mysql, parameters, bind

I am using following query with bind_param:

```
$qry=" UPDATE `prog_m` SET prog_descr=? WHERE prog_id=? ";
$stmt= $conn->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param('si', $content_text, $prog_id);
```

In the code about prog_id is obviously integer if I bind both the variables as string i.e.

```
bind_param('ss', $content_text, $prog_id);
```

still the code works. Can anyone please explain how?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL performs datatype conversions implicitly.

As a demonstration, consider:

```
SELECT 4       + 1
     , ' 4'    + 1
     , '4tune' + 1
```

We can also make datatype conversions explicitly, for example, using `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

Conversion from string to numeric is straightforward. The behavior is documented in MySQL Reference Manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

---

We can observe this behavior in the specific example. Consider the case of a  numeric literal:

```
UPDATE `prog_m` SET prog_descr = 'foo' WHERE prog_id = 42 ;
```

and compare to string literal

```
UPDATE `prog_m` SET prog_descr = 'bar' WHERE prog_id = '42' ;
                                                       ^  ^
```

If `prog_id` column is numeric, MySQL performs implicit conversion of the string literal into numeric.

<strike>If `prog_id` is character type, in the first case, MySQL implicitly converts the numeric literal into a string.</strike>

If `prog_id` is character type column, in the first case, MySQL implicitly converts the column values into numeric, and compares to the numeric literal.

---

Also, kudos for using prepared statements with bind placeholders !

Comment: Great ! thanks a lot for perfect explanation. In the example statement if the prog_id parameter is defined as a string while binding, shall it still protect sql injection ?

Comment: Yes. Using prepared statements with bind placeholders is the normative pattern for mitigating SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Values supplied through bind placeholders/parameters are just that: *values*. It doesn't matter that the value is string. If we are passing an integer value, then it makes sense to specify that as the type in the bind_param. (That better documents our intent, for the benefit of future readers.) Just because it *works* when we bind an integer as a string isn't justification for binding all of our parameters as strings.

Comment: It perfectly clarifies the confusion !